# lapply over lapply (or other way to clean timeseries data)

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to extract some data from a number of excel spreadsheets that do not have a tidy format. I think I need to run lapply within lapply, but can't seem to make it work. Here is an example:

Here are two dataframes with formats equivalent to what i find in the excel sheets:

```
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')
library('readxl')

df1 <- data.frame(instance = c('...', 'A', 'B'), 
                  `1990.1` = c('est', 1, 2), 
                  `1990.2` = c('val', 2, 3),
                  `1991.1` = c('est', 3, 4),
                  `1991.2` = c('val', 4, 5))


df2 <- data.frame(instance = c('...', 'A', 'B'),
                  `1990.1` = c('est', 5, 6), 
                  `1990.2` = c('val', 6, 7),
                  `1991.1` = c('est', 7, 8),
                  `1991.2` = c('val', 8, 9))
> df1
  instance X1990.1 X1990.2 X1991.1 X1991.2
1      ...     est     val     est     val
2        A       1       2       3       4
3        B       2       3       4       5
```

I create a function to clean the data based off:

```
df1 %>%  
  select(1, which(.[1,] == 'est')) %>%
  .[-1,] %>%
  gather(key = year, value = score, -instance) %>%
  mutate(var = 'est')

  instance    year score var
1        A X1990.1     1 est
2        B X1990.1     2 est
3        A X1991.1     3 est
4        B X1991.1     4 est
```

Gives:

```
data_clean <- function(x) {
  df1 %>% 
    select(1, which(.[1,] == x)) %>%
    .[-1,] %>%
    gather(key = year, value = score, -instance) %>%
    mutate(var = x) 
}
```

I can now generate a clean version of each df as follows:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c('est', 'val'), data_clean)) %>% 
  mutate(origin = 'df1')

  instance    year score var origin
1        A X1990.1     1 est    df1
2        B X1990.1     2 est    df1
3        A X1991.1     3 est    df1
4        B X1991.1     4 est    df1
5        A X1990.2     2 val    df1
6        B X1990.2     3 val    df1
7        A X1991.2     4 val    df1
8        B X1991.2     5 val    df1
```

What I now need to do is apply this to the list of dataframes:

```
list_data <- list(df1, df2)
```

In my case i would generate this from a function:

```
data_pull <- function(x) {
  read_excel('path/to/file', sheet = x)
}

list_data <- lapply(2:20, data_pull)
```

But I can't think how to do this. I need to apply data_clean to each element of the list generated by data_pull. I obviously need to remove the first call to df in the data_clean function, but then what object am i passing to data_clean?

What I eventually want is a single data frame with all the data in one place, in a tidy format.

Sorry if i am missing something simple here. I feel there is lots of data that is structured like this and the solution for cleaning it should be fairly simple.I can't seem to think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to keep it in a `list` and loop over the list with `map`.  We can rename the columns by `paste`ing the 1st row for all those columns except the 'instance', `slice` out the first row, use `pivot_longer` to reshape from 'wide' to 'long', `separate` the 'name' column into two, and convert the `type` if needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
f1 <- function(dat) {
        names(dat)[-1] <- str_c(names(dat)[-1], unlist(dat[1,-1]), sep="_")
        dat %>%
           slice(-1) %>%
           pivot_longer(cols = -instance, values_to = "seq" ) %>%
           mutate_all(as.character) %>%
           separate(name, into = c('year', 'var'), sep="_", convert = TRUE) %>%
           type_convert()

}




map_dfr(set_names(list_data, c('df1', 'df2')), f1, .id = 'origin')
# A tibble: 16 x 5
#  origin instance year    var     seq
#   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 df1    A        X1990.1 est       1
# 2 df1    A        X1990.2 val       2
# 3 df1    A        X1991.1 est       3
# 4 df1    A        X1991.2 val       4
# 5 df1    B        X1990.1 est       2
# 6 df1    B        X1990.2 val       3
# 7 df1    B        X1991.1 est       4
# 8 df1    B        X1991.2 val       5
# 9 df2    A        X1990.1 est       5
#10 df2    A        X1990.2 val       6
#11 df2    A        X1991.1 est       7
#12 df2    A        X1991.2 val       8
#13 df2    B        X1990.1 est       6
#14 df2    B        X1990.2 val       7
#15 df2    B        X1991.1 est       8
#16 df2    B        X1991.2 val       9
```

---

If we are using the function `data_pull`

```
map_dfr(2:20, ~ data_pull(.x) %>%
                 f1, .id = 'origin')
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Slowly making my way through what it does. One challenge, i can't seem to run `pivot_longer()`. I get the error: `Error in pivot_longer(., cols = -instance, values_to = "seq") :  could not find function "pivot_longer"` I have `tidyr`, `purrr` and `readr` all installed and loaded.

Comment: @MorrisseyJ  It is introduced in `tidyr 1.0.0`.  Can you check your `packageVersion('tidyr')`

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks i hadn't realized the package was out of date.